# Groupbox for Windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created gui for windows form....!

one side i have groupbox with checkbox and two buttons ">>" and "<<" and on the other side i have one more groupbox.

I need to select one checkbox at a time if the user select more than one checkbox i need to raise error..

if the user selects checkbox and click on ">>" button i need to display number of messages in the other groupbox i.e in the "List of Selected Commands"...
and on the click of ">>" the selected list of message should be deleted from list.

I have included tab control in my gui on click of this tab i need to display some list of commands how can i do it...

can any one help me on this...

This is the code..

```
namespace Menu_Sample
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        groupBox1.Text = "MSC";
        groupBox2.Text = "List Of Selected Commands";
        checkBox1.Visible = false;
        cb2.Visible = false;
        cb3.Visible = false;
        cb4.Visible = false;
        label1.Visible = false;
        label2.Visible = false;
        label3.Visible = false;
        label4.Visible = false;

    }

    private void submenu1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        groupBox1.Text = "ICP";
        checkBox1.Visible = true;
        cb2.Visible = true;
        cb3.Visible = true;
        cb4.Visible = true;
    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            label1.Visible = true;
            label1.Text = "ibit";
            groupBox2.Controls.Add(label1);
            label2.Visible = true;
            label2.Text = "Cbit";
            groupBox2.Controls.Add(label2);
            label3.Visible = true;
            label3.Text = "Kbit";
            groupBox2.Controls.Add(label3);
            label4.Visible = true;
            label4.Text = "ibit";
            groupBox2.Controls.Add(label4);


        }
        if (cb2.Checked == true)
        {
            label1.Visible = true;
            label1.Text = "ibit";
            groupBox2.Controls.Add(label1);
            label2.Visible = true;
            label2.Text = "Cbit";
            groupBox2.Controls.Add(label2);
            label3.Visible = true;
            label3.Text = "Kbit";
            groupBox2.Controls.Add(label3);
            label4.Visible = true;
            label4.Text = "ibit";
            groupBox2.Controls.Add(label4);

        }
    }

    private void btn6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (label1.Enabled==true)
        {
            label1.Text = "";
        }
    }

    private void btn5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "";
        label2.Text = "";
        label3.Text = "";
        label4.Text = "";
    }

    private void submenu2ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        groupBox1.Text = "MCP";
    }

    private void mDPToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        groupBox1.Text = "MDP";
    }

    private void mRPPToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        groupBox1.Text = "MRPP";
    }
  }


}
```

Comment: Why don't you use RadioButton instead of CheckBox?

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you an idea, that how we can do that.

You have to create a group box click event and then use loop for the controls in that groupbox and if that control is checkbox and it is checked, then you just count that no-other checkbox should be checked.

I will be available with the code very shortly.